# Angular: getting data from async; I should not have to force change detection

Tags: angular, pass-by-reference, angular-changedetection

I have this problem too often. Trying to get a list of users (from the database) and show them in

user-admin.component.html:

```
<div class="col-md-2 offset-1">
    <select size=20 [ngStyle]="{'width': '200px'}"> 
      <option *ngFor="let name of userNames">{{name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

user-admin.component.ts

```
  userNames: string[] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private authService: AuthService
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getAllUserNames(this.userNames);
```

getAllUserNames is a function in service: authService.

```
  getAllUserNames(userNames: string[]) {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'usernames').subscribe( (results: string[]) => {
      userNames = results;
    });
  }
```

When the page starts (ngOnInit) and this function is called, it correctly returns 'userNames' with a list of two usernames.
[image]

I can only assume that user-admin.component userNames has the same list.  (I tested the html to be sure it would list the names if they were in the list).

Solution?  I assume I have to force a ChangeDetection and this really doesn't seem like it should be necessary?

OR this.userNames needs to be a reference variable.  I thought it was already (list of strings type).  I tried creating a class with just this.userName as the only content and then passed a 'new AllUsers' class, but the list inside AllUsers didn't show up with the usernames either.

Ideas?
Thanks in advance.
Yogi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the observable returned from the HTTP request in the service and subscribe to it the component. Try the following

user-admin.component.ts

```js
userNames: string[] = [];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.getAllUserNames().subscribe(
    response => { this.userNames = response },
    error => { // handle error }
  );
}
```

authService

```js
getAllUserNames(): Obserable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'usernames');
}
```

Another way would be use [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe where you don't necessarily have to subscribe in the component. But it doesn't make much of a difference in this scenario since `async` usually helps in handling memory leak errors. And here the HTTP client takes care of the memory leak issues, so we don't have to manually unsubscribe in the component.

However if you are using a custom defined Observable and wish to subscribe to it in the component, it is recommended to unsubscribe in the [`OnDestroy`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) hook.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.service.getObservable().subscribe(
      value => { },
      error => { }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was so clearly explained with options.  I learned a lot  AND it works!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you does not need to subscribe in  service instead subscribe insde the component class. Like this you do not need to force change detection. As soon as you update the userNames(component class property) it will automatically render.

```
user-admin.component.ts

  userNames: string[] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private authService: AuthService
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getAllUserNames().subscribe( (results: string[]) => {
      userNames = results;
    });
}

  getAllUserNames(userNames: string[]) {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'usernames');
  }
```